# Из xls в базу sql

Tags: sql, xls

Здравствуйте, есть xls список который выглядит так

[Таблица http://take.ms/10y3C](http://take.ms/10y3C)

и есть sql таблица в таком формате,

[Код SQL http://take.ms/qHHwI](http://take.ms/qHHwI)

есть ли способ перенести данные из таблицы xls в sql автоматом? Расположение таблицы такое же как и должно быть в sql.

Comment: Напрямую sql не умеет читать xls. В контексте языков высоких уровней c# c++ php питон - есть библиотеки которые позволяют импортировать xls. Но некоторые, например mssql позволяют получать данные из источников oledb или odbc (если есть драйвер на excel на серверах часто его нету), или подключать внешние библиотеки и загружать данные посредством библиотеки (что впринципе не является sql).

Comment: Уточните какими средствами вы хотите сделать, и какой обьём таблиц. Вручную хотите конвертировать или автоматически, если автоматически то какие технологии языки хотите использовать.

Answer (score 1):

Да такая возможность есть.

Excel позволяет сохранить данные в формате CSV. А большинство SQL баз данных поддерживает загрузку данных из CSV файлов. Сам синтаксис разнится в зависимости от конкретной реализации базы, но такая возможность есть.

Ну и как вариант - CSV это обычный текстовый формат. Всегда можно сделать простейший скрипт, который будет на его основе формировать SQL код.

Comment: Ваш вариант "ручной" врядли подойдёт.

Comment: @nick_n_a что-то мне подсказывает что для автора вопроса "ручной" вариант - это копипаст из Excel в SQL запросы. И поэтому любое убыстрение процесса - это уже автоматика.

Comment: Если это разовый вариант - Тогда лучше с помощью функции обьеденить - получить сразу sql:)

Answer (score 1):

К MS Excel, можно также обращаться при помощи SQL запросов из кода на VB.Net или C#, т.е., если я правильно понимаю прочитать данные в одном месте и записать в другое место, хотя не совсем понятно про форматы ссылок о которых Вы говорите. Еще как вариант, если у вас есть MS Access, то можно импортировать в Access данные из Excel и затем экспортировать их на SQL Server.

Comment: Не спешите писать ответ. Ваш ответ выглядит как уточнение, и не является качественным. Дождитесь репутации в 10 балл и вы сможете оставлять коментарии.

Answer (score 1):

Если записей не много можно сформировать команду INSERT путем сцепления значений таблицы, но в таком случае необходимо сначала создать эту таблицу и описать поля. Строка будет примерно такого вида: = СЦЕПИТЬ("insert into MyTable values (";A1;",";B1;",";C1;")")